# Trying to deploy django app to heroku and having an issue with collect static storage.py path

Tags: python, django, web, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django project to heroku and having a hard time with the static files. I have everything set up properly as it has worked for me in the past. I'm not sure what the issue is this time.

Below is my traceback. It seems to be something with the static files path but it shouldnt have a problem if I have my STATIC ROOT and URL correct right?

-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>

       main()

     File "manage.py", line 18, in main

       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line

       utility.execute()

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute

       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv

       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute

       output = self.handle(*args, **options)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 194, in handle

       collected = self.collect()

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 109, in collect

       for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 130, in list

       for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files

       directories, files = storage.listdir(location)

     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir

       for entry in os.scandir(path):

   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_0728dd1c_/static'
```

Please help. I know the Static File deployment with heroku is a nightmare but I tried all the troubleshooting and still cant solve the problem here.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: was told to add the static settings...

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: Did you by chance put `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py` and put either `/static/` or `BASEDIR / 'static'` in it?

Comment: Please share `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have this variables properly configured in `settings.py` file:

```
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]


MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

Try installing whitenoise using `pip install whitenoise` then add this line to your `MIDDLEWARE` list in `settings.py`: `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',`

Also add this variable along with static variables:

`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

Do not forget to add whitenoise in your requirements.txt file.

Comment: Yes its configured correctly. Thats why I dont know what the issue is. Could it be that I had a github repo and then tried to push to the heroku repo? It might have made two static directories?

Comment: That can't be an issue

Comment: If I disable collect static it deploys but I still get an application error from heroku and told to check the logs

Comment: I have updated the answer, try that again. Do not disable collect static

Comment: I think I've figured out a way to collect the static files and deliver them now. I ran collect static locally and got it to work then pushed it but my slug is now too big. When I checked the dyno it was showing that I had almost like 2 apps or something?

Comment: It was showing 300mb /app/ then 300mb /app/.heroku or something

Comment: @Vandle0 Actually Whitenoise works fine for me, you can check this video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBwhtEIXGII&t=922s